# How to check "IF any one or all buttons are clicked" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I want to enable and disable a button using jquery.

As per my code I have few sets of "Accept" and "Reject" buttons and 1 "Authorize" button, so as per logic, when all "Accept" button are "Accepted" the "Authorize" button should be enabled and if even 1  Reject button is clicked, the Authorize button should be rejected.

Can you please help me in how to check for "if any one or all buttons are clicked".

here is my code below:

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="content-1">
    <div class="rx-statusbuttons">
        <input type="button" value="Accepted" class="Accepted" />
        <input type="button" value="Rejected" class="Rejected redButton" />
    </div>
    <div class="rx-statusMessage">
        <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
        <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content-2">
    <div class="rx-statusbuttons">
        <input type="button" value="Accepted" class="Accepted" />
        <input type="button" value="Rejected" class="Rejected redButton" />
    </div>
    <div class="rx-statusMessage">
        <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
        <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content-3">
    <div class="rx-statusbuttons">
        <input type="button" value="Accepted" class="Accepted" />
        <input type="button" value="Rejected" class="Rejected redButton" />
    </div>
    <div class="rx-statusMessage">
        <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
        <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Authorize" disabled="disabled" id="authorizeButton" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content-1 .Accepted").click(function () {
        $('#content-1 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-1 .rx-statusRejected').hide();
        $("#content-1 .rx-statusAccepted").show();

    });
    $("#content-1 .Rejected").click(function () {
        $('#content-1 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-1 .rx-statusRejected').show();
        $("#content-1 .rx-statusAccepted").hide();

    });

    $("#content-2 .Accepted").click(function () {
        $('#content-2 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-2 .rx-statusRejected').hide();
        $("#content-2 .rx-statusAccepted").show();
    });
    $("#content-2 .Rejected").click(function () {
        $('#content-2 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-2 .rx-statusRejected').show();
        $("#content-2 .rx-statusAccepted").hide();
    });

    $("#content-3 .Accepted").click(function () {
        $('#content-3 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-3 .rx-statusRejected').hide();
        $("#content-3 .rx-statusAccepted").show();

    });
    $("#content-3 .Rejected").click(function () {
        $('#content-3 .rx-statusbuttons').hide();
        $('#content-3 .rx-statusRejected').show();
        $("#content-3 .rx-statusAccepted").hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.nodisplay {
    display:none;
}
#content-1, #content-2, #content-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**Here if the Fiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/QvB37/**

I also tried using **.length** but I am not sure how to use it in my logic.

Please suggest.

Comment: Control it with 1 function. On click of reject or activate, test whether or not they are all activated. if they're all activated, enable the button, else hide it. I think you're overcomplicating it.

Comment: You could set a variable for each button that either is equal to true or false, and then do an if statement on the authorize button that checks to see if those variables are equal to true, and if so, display the button, but if not, then hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little change to HTML and You can simplify your code in one function for Accept and Reject. See below,

**Note:**

1. Added content class to all container elements with id `content-#`
2. Revised the condition to Authorize with number of `visible Accepted` == `Accepted.length`

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Accepted").click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.content');
        $('.rx-statusbuttons', $parent).hide();
        $('.rx-statusRejected', $parent).hide();
        $('.rx-statusAccepted', $parent).show();
        checkIfAccepted();
    });
    $(".Rejected").click(function () {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.content');
        $('.rx-statusbuttons', $parent).hide();
        $('.rx-statusRejected', $parent).show();
        $(".rx-statusAccepted", $parent).hide();
    });
});

function checkIfAccepted() {
    if ($(".rx-statusAccepted:visible").length == $(".rx-statusAccepted").length) {
        $('#authorizeButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

**Updated DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jG6Ue/

Comment: Superb... It works... n best this is with the updated code I need not worry.. there can be as many sets of buttons!! and thanku for telling me the easier and shorter way of doing hide show too.. It helps!!!

Comment: Hey, like you resolved this issue, I am having similar issue.. Can you please look into it and suggest something?? Will be much appreciated!!!    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011408/how-to-manage-same-jquery-ui-dialog-opening-from-multiple-buttons

Answer (score 2):

How about just testing the length of the class visible?

```
function checkIfAccepted() { 
      if($(".rx-statusAccepted:visible").length == 3) {
            $('#authorizeButton').prop('disabled', false);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!! But the selected answer is simple awesome and will work even if in future I have mare than 3 boxes :-)

Comment: sure, glad you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this `$("#authorizeButton").removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: Thank you for the help, I knew I can do it by adding this $("#authorizeButton").removeAttr("disabled");.... all i wanted to know that how I can incorporate the IF Else logic for doing.. see the selected answer.. hope that would be a new learning!!!