# How to manage "same jquery ui dialog" opening from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 button one will open Dialog box and make some changes with its `<div>` and the will not open any dialog box, it will just make some styling changes within its `<DIV>`

I will have multiple instances of the `<DIV>s` which contains these 2 buttons these `<DIV>s` will be generating at runtime so there can be "N" number of buttons.

**I have created the FIDDLE to give a demo of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/ZtLEq/**

Now, for the button which "DOES NOT" generate Dialog Box, I am able to make changes using jquery by catching its "`.closest ('parent div')`" and then on click of this particular button, it make changes for its parent `<DIV>` only.

BUt the ISSUE IS: with the button which generates Dialog Box, I am not sure on click of which button the dialog box have been generated, so on submit I am not sure which particular parent `<Div>` should be impacted.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content-1" class="content">
    <div class="rx-container"> <span title="Accept" class="Accepted">Accept</span>

        <br>
        <br> <span title="Reject" class="Rejected">Reject</span>

        <div class="rx-statusMessage">
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
            <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
            <div class="rejectReasonBox nodisplay">Reason: <span>Incorrect Label Applied</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-2" class="content">
    <div class="rx-container"> <span title="Accept" class="Accepted">Accept</span>

        <br>
        <br> <span title="Reject" class="Rejected">Reject</span>

        <div class="rx-statusMessage">
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
            <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
            <div class="rejectReasonBox nodisplay">Reason: <span>Incorrect Label Applied</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-3" class="content">
    <div class="rx-container"> <span title="Accept" class="Accepted">Accept</span>

        <br>
        <br> <span title="Reject" class="Rejected">Reject</span>

        <div class="rx-statusMessage">
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="rx-statusAccepted nodisplay">Accepted</p>
            <p class="rx-statusRejected nodisplay">Rejected</p>
            <div class="rejectReasonBox nodisplay">Reason: <span>Incorrect Label Applied</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rejectReason" title="Reason">
    <p>Please provide the reason for cancelling the session.</p>
    <div class="inputRow">
        <textarea id="rejectReasonBox" class="reasonBox">Incorrect Label Applied</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    function aceeptMethod() {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.rx-container');

        $('.rx-statusRejected', $parent).hide();
        $('.rx-statusAccepted', $parent).show();
        $('.rejectReasonBox', $parent).hide();
        $('.k-tabstrip-items .k-state-default .k-link', $parent).css('color', '#7ea700');
        $('.k-tabstrip .k-state-active', $parent).css('border-color', '#7ea700');
        $('.k-tabstrip-items .k-state-active, .k-tabstrip .k-content.k-state-active', $parent).css('background-color', '#f5f5e9');


        $(this).attr("title", "Accepted");
        $(this).next().attr("title", "Reject");

        $(this).removeClass('Accepted');
        $(this).addClass('disableAccepted');
        $(this).next().removeClass('disableRejected');
        $(this).next().addClass('Rejected');

        checkIfAccepted();
    }

    function rejectMethod() {
        $('.k-tabstrip-items .k-state-default .k-link').css('color', '#ff0000');
        $('.k-tabstrip .k-state-active').css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        $('.k-tabstrip-items .k-state-active,#content-1 .k-tabstrip .k-content.k-state-active').css('background-color', '#f5e9e9');
        $('.rx-statusRejected').show();
        $(".rx-statusAccepted").hide();
        $(".rejectReasonBox").show();

        $('.Rejected').attr("title", "Rejected");


        $('.Rejected').prev().attr("title", "Accept");
        $('.Rejected').addClass('disableRejected');
        $('.disableRejected').prev().addClass('Accepted');
        $('.disableRejected').prev().removeClass('disableAccepted');
        $('.disableRejected').removeClass('Rejected');
        checkIfRejected();
    }



    $("#rejectReason").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                rejectMethod();
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


    $(".Accepted").click(aceeptMethod);
    $(".Rejected").click(function () {
        $("#rejectReason").dialog("open");
    });


    function checkIfAccepted() {
        if ($(".rx-statusAccepted:visible").length == $(".rx-statusAccepted").length) {
            $('#authorizeOrderButton').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#authorizeOrderButton').removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#authorizeOrderButton').removeClass("greyButton");
        }
    }

    function checkIfRejected() {
        if ($(".rx-statusAccepted:visible").length <= $(".rx-statusAccepted").length) {
            $('#authorizeOrderButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#authorizeOrderButton').addClass("greyButton");
        }
    }

});
```

Please suggest!

Let me know if you need some more informatuion or if the situation is not clear.

Thanks!

Comment: can start at simplest level...toggle a class on parent container of button on open, find that class and remove it within dialog close event and/or submit handler. Not enough...pass data regarding parent to hidden field in submittal form. Add `data-` attributes to elements to store needed identifiers, read with `jQuery.data()`...could have them right on buttons and not even need to traverse to parent

Comment: Can you help me by creating some Fiddle or something?? or by modifying my own Fiddle?? I tried adding class to that particular div, the class got added, but somehow now my rest of the code stopped working.. :-(

Comment: here is the updated Fiddle with what I did..  http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/KC9yW/

Comment: here's a good start....what you have is far far too complicated. I only got some basics working to have proper rejection shown  http://jsfiddle.net/ZtLEq/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per "**`charlietfl Nov 15 at 23:06`**" suggestion I was able to fix my issue:

"*here's a good start....what you have is far far too complicated. I only got some basics working to have proper rejection shown **[jsfiddle.net/ZtLEq/6](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtLEq/6)** –  charlietfl Nov 15 at 23:06*"

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to take advantage of closures and the click event's `target` parameter.

Instead of defining the dialog and calling "open" on it later, you should call it when you actually need the dialog box to open within the click event like so:

```
$(".accept").click(function(e){
    $("#rejectReason").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                myUi._rejectMethod(e.target);
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This allows you to pass the button that was click through so you know which one you are working with.

[Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/ZtLEq/5/)